# Up/down arrow key commands

Tags: ios, objective-c

There are sources with these rules. I've listed the source too much, but I want to make it shorter and easier.

```
-(void)upArrow:(UIKeyCommand*)keyCommand
{
    if (buttonTag == 1) {
        buttonTag = 6; // -5
    } else if(buttonTag == 2) {
        buttonTag = 7; // -5
    } else if(buttonTag == 3) {
        buttonTag = 1; // +2
    } else if((buttonTag == 4) || (buttonTag == 5)) {
        buttonTag = 2;  // +2
    } else if(buttonTag == 6) {
        buttonTag = 3;  // -3
    } else if(buttonTag == 7) {
        buttonTag = 4; // -3
    }
}

-(void)downArrow:(UIKeyCommand*)keyCommand
{
    if (buttonTag == 1) {
        buttonTag = 3; // +2
    } else if(buttonTag == 2) {
        buttonTag = 4; // +2
    } else if(buttonTag == 3) {
        buttonTag = 6; // +3
    } else if((buttonTag == 4) || (buttonTag == 5)) {
        buttonTag = 7; // +3
    } else if(buttonTag == 6) {
        buttonTag = 1; // -5
    } else if(buttonTag == 7) {
        buttonTag = 2;  // -5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create an array that contains result values for upArrow, and another array for values of buttonTag for downArrow. Arrays are zero-indexed, so subtract 1 from your buttonTag value before using it as an array index (and bounds check it).

You could create a function to remap button tags. The one for the up button tags might look like this:

```
- (int) remapUpButtonTag: (int) buttonTag {
  int tags[] = {6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4};
  int arraySize = (int) sizeof(tags)/sizeof(int);
  if (buttonTag < 1 || buttonTag > arraySize) { return -1; }
  return tags[buttonTag-1];
}

-(void)upArrow:(UIKeyCommand*)keyCommand {
  buttonTag = [self remapUpButtonTag: buttonTag];
}
```

(Note that it's written to return -1 if the input tag is out of range.)

Comment: Array isn't the best solution, because it requires indexes to go in a row. Better use `NSDictionary`, where `NSNumber` will be a key.

Comment: An array works fine if the tags are sequential. If not, you're right that a dictionary keyed with a tag number would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be too concerned about the 'shortest' solution. What you want is clean code that makes sense.

So first get rid of all those magic numbers and use enumerated constants.

Now change the if/else if to a switch.